# (complex variables) Calculate the integrals below using the theory seen on Cauchy's integral formula. Do not use the formula that involves ...

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, problem-solving, complex-integration

> Calculate the integrals below using the theory seen on Cauchy's integral formula. Do not use the formula that involves parameterization.

> a)$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz$, where $\gamma(t) = e^{it}, 0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

> b)$\int_{\gamma} \frac{log z}{(z-1)^n}dz$, where $\gamma(t) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}e^{it} , 0 \le t \le 2\pi$ e $n \in \mathbb N$.

a)Let $a=0,n=1,f(z) = e^{iz} \to f'(z) = ie^{iz}$ so $f(z)$ is analitic on $\mathbb C$ and $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb C$. From

> $$ f^{n(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw$$ where $\gamma (t) = a + re^{it}, 0 \le t \le 2 \pi$.

We have

$f'(0) = \frac{1!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{(z-0)^2} dz \to i = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz \to \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz = - 2 \pi$.

b)Let $a =-1, n=n,f(z)=log z \to f'(1)= \frac{1}{zln10} \to f^{2}= - \frac{1}{z^2 ln 10} \to f^{3}= \frac{2}{z^3 ln 10} \to f^{4}= - \frac{6}{z^4 ln 10} \to f^{5}=  \frac{24}{z^5 ln 10}$

I think a) is correct but I'm stuck on b).

Thanks.

Comment: I will say that in the context of such problems the use of "$\log$" might actually mean that the base is $e$, not $10$ (looking at the factor of $1/\ln(10)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy integral formula says:

$\oint \frac {f(z)}{z-a}^n \ dz = 2\pi i \frac {f^{(n-1)}(a)}{(n-1)!}$

But, calculating those derivatives can be a pain in the butt.  Here is a shortcut.

Remember that that the Taylor series of a function is:

$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(z-a) + \cdots +\frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(z-a)^n + \cdots$

Those coefficients are exactly what we are looking for.  If we know the Talor series of our function, all we have to do is find the right coefficient.

$\log z = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (z-1)^n$

(in complex analysis and every math class thereafter "log" should be assumed to be $\ln$)

When $n>1$
$\oint \frac {\log z}{(z-1)^n} \ dz = 2\pi i\frac {(-1)^{n}}{n-1}$

Comment: Shouldn't the $n-1$ in the denominator not be there?

Comment: @Cpc as you note in your answer, $\frac {d^n}{dz^n} \log z |_1 = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!$ then $\frac {\frac {d^n}{dz^n} \log z}{n!}|_1 = \frac {(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Comment: Right, so that turns the n in the denominator from $n$  to $n-1$ or the $n-1$th derivative evaluated at 1 is $ (-1)^{n} (n-2)!$ and when we divide that by $(n-1)!$ we get $\frac {(-1)^n}{n-1}$

Comment: You're right,  I was off by one.

Comment: One more thing.   $+1$ but, the derivatives of $\log z$ are pretty easy to compute.

Comment: Sure, not bad, but this idea with the Talor series is worth knowing, as is the Talor series of the "standard" functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

For $b)$, you can see that $f^{(n)}(1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!$.

There's no $\ln10$, because $\log z$ means the principal branch of log.